# Computing the expected size of the largest connected component in a "hitomezashi graph" (described in the question body)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory

A while ago there was a [numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbfhzlMk2eY) about a certain graph you can build based on [Hitomezashi Sashiko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sashiko), a kind of decorative mending.

Intuitively, we alternate putting walls (originally stitches) in each column/row, which separate the integer lattice into components. $s_1$ governs the positions of the vertical walls and $s_2$ governs the positions of the horizontal walls. A $0$ tells us to start "at the edge" and a $1$ tells us to start "off the edge". For example, choosing $s_1 = 01101$ and $s_2 = 10110$ gives the following stitch pattern.

[image: the stitch pattern]

If we think of each unit square as a vertex, with adjacent cells connected whenever there isn't a wall separating them, we get a graph, $H(s_1,s_2)$:

[image: the graph overlayed on the stitching]

If it's still unclear how the walls work, it's made clear in the first few minutes of the linked numberphile video. For those looking for a precise description, formally, we build a graph $H(s_1, s_2)$ given two binary strings (say of length $n_1$ and $n_2$) as follows

- $[n_1] \times [n_2]$ is the vertex set ($0$ indexed)
- $(x,y) \sim (x+1,y)$ whenever $y \not \equiv s_1[x+1] \pmod{2}$
- $(x,y) \sim (x,y+1)$ whenever $x \not \equiv s_2[y+1] \pmod{2}$

I also have [a demo](https://grossack.site/2021/12/08/hitomezashi-maker) on my blog where you can input binary strings and it will output a picture of the graph.

---

Now, if we do this with longer binary strings, we get some quite intricate pictures:

[image: a larger example]

and there are some natural questions to ask. I've put a fair amount of my thoughts about these problems in [a different blog post](https://grossack.site/2021/12/19/hitomezashi-mathematics.html), but here is the one I'm primarily interested in:

> Say we (uniformly) randomly choose two binary strings of a fixed length $n$. What is the expected size of the largest connected component of $H(s_1, s_2)$ as a function of $n$?

I'm not much of a probabilistic combinatorialist, so I pretty quickly exhausted my personal bag of tricks for attacking these kinds of problems. But this *feels* like something that somebody knows how to answer (and ideally, something somebody would *enjoy* answering ^_^).

I recognize this is probably hard to answer, so I'm open to partial progress. In particular, I wrote some [sage](https://sagemath.org) code to get some data, and here's a graph of the average maximum region size (across a few hundred samples) as a function of $n$:

[image: the data plus a curve of best fit]

The blue curve is the polynomial of best fit, which turns out to be $\approx 1.95 n^{1.38}$

This brings us to some (hopefully easier) problems:

> Can we show that the expected size of the largest component is $o(n^2)$? What about $o(n^{1.5})$? Is it possible to pin down the exponent exactly? Can we get lower bounds too?

You can find more of my thoughts, as well as some code for simulating these things yourself if you're interested, in my blog post [here](https://grossack.site/2021/12/19/hitomezashi-mathematics.html). I'm open to hearing any thoughts that people have about this, because I really have no idea how to proceed.

---

**Edit (Jan 5):**

Based on the new data from Daniel Mathias, it seems a good conjecture is $\frac{8}{3} n^{4/3}$. I've added a $50$ rep bounty as thanks, and afterwards I'll add a $100$ rep bounty for a proof of this conjecture (or some substantial progress). I need to wait $24$ hours before I can post that second bounty, though.

---

Thanks in advance! ^_^

Comment: Would the downvoter explain their issue with this question?

Comment: This is interesting. In the very least, it provided a fun little coding project. I might not be able to offer any insights, but I can generate a lot more data. For $n=1000$ I find an average maximum region size of $26422$ across ten thousand samples.

Comment: @DanielMathias -- If you post your code (maybe in a pastebin?) and plot the data, plus a new approximation based on the data (which should hopefully be $\approx 1.95 n^{1.38}$) and a description of how many samples you do for each $n$, I would definitely upvote it! More data more better. Out of curiosity, what language did you use?

Comment: Small run (1,000 sample for each $n$): Google docs [spreadsheet with chart](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13FUTAoTYzpxXOqxgND8u0PWX58TCGiCU46fH0pEYjpg/edit?usp=sharing) $1.95 n^{1.38}$ is still a good fit, but $\frac83n^{4/3}$ looks better. Larger run with at least 10,000 samples for each $n$ will be provided tomorrow, along with the C code used to generate the data.

Comment: @DanielMathias -- <3

Comment: In case you missed it, I added a second chart with extended data a few days ago. I have just now updated that chart with a new estimate.

Comment: And now for a small sample of larger values: [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg5hM.png)

Comment: A comment on a broad generalization: According to [this paper](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1960-10.pdf) of Erdős and Rényi, for any constant $c>0$, the expected size $f_c(n)$ of the greatest component of a random graph $G(n,c/n)$ (where each edge of a complete graph on $n$ vertices is retained with probability $c/n$) satisfies $f_c(n)=O(\log n)$ for $c<1$, $f_c(n)=\Theta(n^{2/3})$ for $c=1$, and $f_c(n)=\Theta(n)$ for $c>1$. The graph $H(s_1,s_2)$ is a graph on $n^2$ vertices, and so the expectation $\Theta(n^{4/3})$ patterns quite well with Erdős and Rényi's "boundary case"...

Comment: ... $H(s_1,s_2)$ is clearly not a perfectly random graph, and it also has twice as many edges as would guarantee boundary behavior for a completely random graph, but it is bipartite. Exercise 2.4.8 of "Introduction to Random Graphs" by Frieze and Karoński suggests that the threshold number of edges for a random bipartite graph for this behavior is the number of vertices, rather than half the number of vertices. This means that the answer being $\Theta(n^{4/3})$ would probably be in line with the heuristic that $H$ behaves like a random bipartite graph on $n^2$ vertices with $n^2$ edges.

Comment: (It may be worth noting that the proof of this $n^{2/3}$ bound for Erdős-Rényi random graphs definitely doesn't generalize at all to this setting, or even to the more general setting of taking a random subgraph of the $n\times n$ grid graph. The proof makes crucial use of the fact that connected components are very likely to be trees or nearly trees, which very much isn't the case here -- we'd expect $\Omega(n^2)$ $8$-cycles, for example. So, if indeed the $4/3$ exponent is correct, it's probably somewhat of a coincidence, or the result of a much more adaptable proof strategy.)

Answer (score 2):

As promised, I have generated a more substantial amount of data to provide a more accurate plot.
[image]
Blue line is average maximum region size across 10,000 samples for $n=10k;5\le k\le 100$
Red dotted line is $1.95n^{1.38}$ and green dotted line (yes, it's there) is $\frac83n^{4/3}$

C source code: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/5mGzAXZ2)
As-is, the code runs only 1000 samples at each size. Run-time $\approx4\frac12$ minutes.

---

**Edit:**

More data from an extended run. The averages gradually fall short of the estimate. A new estimate of $2.9n^{1.32}$ is shown in dotted yellow over the blue data line.

[image]

Comment: The spreadsheet linked in comments above has been updated with this data.